# Вывод текста в TextView в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-asynctask

Ниже представляю `AsyncTask`, который находится в адаптере. В `doInBackground()` выполняется парсинг с помощью Jsoup, далее в `onPostExecute()` устанавливается текст в TextView.

```
private class Content2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document htmlTags = null;

        try {
            String htmlUrl = "http://www.cinemaplus.az/ru";
            htmlTags = Jsoup.connect(htmlUrl).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            Elements moviesContainer = htmlTags.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "sortable_movie_home");

            for (Element movieContainer : moviesContainer) {
                moviesNames.add(movieContainer.select("h2").text());
                moviesUrls.add("http://www.cinemaplus.az" + movieContainer.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("src", "site/assets").attr("src"));
                    }
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mItemText.setText(moviesNames.get(positionNext));
        Picasso.get().load(moviesUrls.get(positionNext)).into(mItemImage);
    }
}
```

Адаптер, в котором находится `AsyncTask`:

```
public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<String> moviesNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> moviesUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    private TextView mItemText;
    private ImageView mItemImage;

    private int positionNext;

    private Content2 content;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesNames.size();
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView){
            super (itemView);

            mItemText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mItemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_background);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            content = new Content2();
            content.execute();
            positionNext = position;
        }

        public void onClick(View view){
        }

    }
```

По идее данные должны выводиться в виде карточек в RecyclerView, однако на деле отображается только первый элемент.

Как я могу вывести все элементы? Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: На мой взгляд - логика вашего Async Task должна возвращать два массива или же массив записей ViewModel вида - название + URL, onPostExecute должен его сетить в адаптер, и адаптер инвалидировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от лишних списков создадим модель Film.java:

```
public class Film {
String name;
String urls;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Film film = (Film) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, film.name) &&
            Objects.equals(urls, film.urls);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, urls);
}}
```

Подправим PopularAdapter.java:

```
public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private ArrayList<Film> movies = new ArrayList<>();

private TextView mItemText;
private ImageView mItemImage;


public void addList(ArrayList<Film> names) {
    movies.addAll(names);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mItemText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mItemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_background);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bindView(int position) {
        mItemText.setText(movies.get(position).name);
        Picasso.get().load(movies.get(position).urls).into(mItemImage);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
    }

}}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv;
PopularAdapter rvAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rvAdapter = new PopularAdapter();
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

    Content2 content = new Content2();
    content.execute();

}

class Content2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Film>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Film> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document htmlTags = null;
        ArrayList<Film> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String htmlUrl = "http://www.cinemaplus.az/ru";
            htmlTags = Jsoup.connect(htmlUrl).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements moviesContainer = htmlTags.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "sortable_movie_home");

        for (Element movieContainer : moviesContainer) {
            Film item = new Film();
            item.name = movieContainer.select("h2").text();
            item.urls = "http://www.cinemaplus.az" + movieContainer.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("src", "site/assets").attr("src");
            list.add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Film> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        rvAdapter.addList(result);
    }
}}
```